# Inheritance versus composition python class for frequency data using pandas DataFrame

Tags: oop, python-2.7, pandas

I am just learning OOP in Python 2.7 and I want to put together a class that handles frequency data with the following structure:

```
"Freq"    "Device 1"    "Device 2"    etc.....
 100        90           95
 500        95           100
  .          .            .
  .          .            .
```

My first thought was to use a composition of a dataframe to represent the data above along with a units attribute to track the units (ex Volts vs milliVolts).

I want to be able to use all of the built in functionality of pandas, like being able to merge DataFrames together, slicing, indexing, plotting etc. I also want to keep track of the units of the data so that when I merge, plot, etc. I can adjust values so they are congruent.

If I create a class based on composition, I find merging is difficult

```
class FreqData(object):
    __init__(self, data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, 
                   copy=False, units=None):
        self.df = DataFrame(data, index, columns, dtype, copy)
        self.units = units
```

Then my merge method looks something like this

```
    def combine(self, fds, axis=1):

        try:
            chk_units = self.units == fds.units
            fds = [fds]
        except AttributeError:
            chk_units = all([self.units == f.units for f in fds])

        combined_fd = FreqData()
        if chk_units:
            combined_fd.units = self.units
            df_list = [f.df for f in fds]
            df_list.insert(0, self.df)
            combined_fd.df = pd.concat(df_list, axis=1)
            return combined_fd
        else:
            raise TypeError("""One or more of the FreqData objects measurement
                        types does not match""")
```

Is there an easier way to do this using composition or should I try using inheritance?

Also, I want to use slicing methods like df[], but I'd like to be able to do this on the FreqData object rather than having to write a method like:

```
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        fd = FreqData()
        fd.df = self.df.__getitem__(key)
        fd.units = self.units
        return fd
```

This seems like a bunch of redundant code. How can I improve this?